# Travel to UK (vacation) with British Wife on pre-Brexit German Residence Card without visitors visa

Tags: uk-citizens, visa-free-entry, south-african-citizens, vacations

Framing our situation:

- Live in Germany, Berlin
- Wife is British (Dual Citizen)
- We arrived AUG 2019 - so pre-Brexit
- Family are South African passport holders
- All of us have Aufenthaltsdokument-GB residence cards

Question:

Are we able to travel to the UK for a vacation without visas for myself and the children?

I was under the impression that so long as my wife (British) travelled with us the visa could be waived. But I would like the document that indicates this before I book travel.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y?

Comment: I did yes, and the suggestion was a family visa, which was confusing as the page indicated a lengthy stay rather than a simple visit? Does this make sense for the scenario, it appears that you can apply online for free